# Android service does not start immediately

Tags: android, multithreading, service

```
public class TestService extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Intent service=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MessageListener.class);

        Log.v("Test", "Going to start service");    
        startService(service);
        Log.v("Test", "service started?");

    }
}

public class MessageListener extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v("Test", "Start Cmd");
        intent.setAction("Started");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i=100;i<200;i++){
                    Log.v("Test",i+"");
                }

            }
        }).start();
        return START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.v("Test", "Create");
    }
```

I expect it would print:

```
Start Service
create
Start cmd
print 1->100
Service Started.
```

But I'm getting

```
Start Service
Service Started.
create 
Start cmd
prints 1->100
```

Why is it?

---

I've found the problem is due to Asynchronous. startService will be called after parent's method finished. 
The solution is:

```
public class TestService extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       Intent service=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MessageListener.class);

               startService(service);

               mCheckerHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_CHECK_SERVICE_RUNNING, 100);
   }

   private static final int MSG_CHECK_SERVICE_RUNNING = 0x001122;

   private Handler mCheckerHandler = new Handler() {
           public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                   if (msg.what == MSG_CHECK_SERVICE_RUNNING) {
                           if (checkServiceRunning()) {
                                   //Do something
                           } else {
                                   //Send another message to check in the next 100ms
                                   sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_CHECK_SERVICE_RUNNING, 100);
                           }
                   }
           };
   };
}
```

Thanks for all of you. Especially to Mr Binh :)

Comment: Didn't understand what are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: You didn't getting `Service started` at all?

Comment: Yes, I did, it's after Start Service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the thread is executing in "pseudo"-parallel so the `Log.v("Test", "service started?");` is called before the counter-thread gets any CPU-time to write.

"Pseudo"-parallel because most phones don't have more than 1 CPU so they cannot compute in parallel so they only switch from one thread to another. You can read more about threading on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29) or any other source you like.

Comment: The issue still occurs when I dont use the Thread. Android Document says that the service will run on the same process with the main activity. I thought it would print in order?

Comment: But the documentation also tells you that "The startService() method returns immediately and the Android system calls the service's onStartCommand() method." ;)

Comment: @alopix - you mean what service is started in the same process and in the same thread as the activity what is initiated service start???

Comment: @Olegas An android service is started and executed in the main process of the app (unless otherwise declared). And because it does not spawn a new  thread it will be executed on the main thread of the app.